# In a Jenkins multi-branch pipeline, anyway to programmatically set which branches to scan?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using a Jenkins multi-branch pipeline, and set it to "Discover branches" and "Filter by name (with wildcards)" as shown in screen shot. I currently have it set to `feature/*` but we have a LOT of feature branches on a LOT of repos, and it's very taxing to the system. Anyway to set this value programmatically, so I only set it to a certain value, e.g., `feature/ticket-123-fix-this`?

[image]

Comment: Just a heads up, even if you have a lot of branches and repos it doesn't take Jenkins a lot to scan all of them. Just make sure that  in the "Automatic branch project triggering" section you set the suppression strategy to "For matching branches suppress builds triggered by indexing" so that scanning the repos doesn't result in all them being built as well.

Comment: I do this on the GUI, but per question, how to do it programmatically?

Comment: Take a look at [this script](https://github.com/peterjenkins1/jenkins-scripts/blob/master/add-multibranch-pipeline-job.groovy) - should give you the direction you need